# Excel - Need to create a dropdown list (data validation) refers to two or more columns

Tags: excel

I want to restrict a value in excel sheet , where it should accept only the values available in certain columns in a different excel file.
Eg:

Excel1.xls

```
Col1  Col2  
A      E  
B      F  
C
```

Excel2.xls

Col3
*should accept only (A,B,C,E,F) which are available in Col1,Col2

Comment: Partial Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956560/excel-data-validation. In this case you could use `join([transpose(a1:a3)],",") & "," & join([transpose(b1:b2)],",")` as the list source.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for asking this question - earlier I was not sure about the answer.
But now, I am sure to do this.

I suggest you to check the complete solution from here : http://www.contextures.on.ca/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. If you gave the OP a full working solution, you would more likely desserve upvotes

Comment: -1 :( This does not answer the OP question.  What was asked for is a validation list consisting of values from _multiple_ columns.  The link deals with dynamic lists, where the list is returned from one of many columns, but ultimately the validation list is contained in one column.